# kubernete Master node not able to access application using master node ip

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes , I have created two `ec2  ubuntu:20 instances` in aws and enabled the  required ports using security-groups, two nodes i mean master-node and worker-node are working fine and i deployed the webapp using yaml file, pod and svc are working fine.

However when i copy and paste master-node ip:port in browser, master-node cant able to access  the application but when i use the worker-node able to access the application

if any one suggested me that would be helpfull for me

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapp-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapp
  replicas: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webapp
        image: janaid/demoreactjs
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapp-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: webapp
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 32001
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

hello, hope you are enjoying your kubernetes journey!

This is probably because by default, your master node is only used for the kubernetes control plane and not for your applications workloads.

That means that your webapp pod will only be deployed on your worker node

However, to enable your master node to accept workloads deployed on it, you have to remove the native taint label on the master node (not a best practice) here is a guide you can follow:

> [https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-schedule-pods-on-kubernetes-control-plane-node/#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20be,taint%20on%20the%20master%20nodes.&text=This%20will%20remove%20the%20node,able%20to%20schedule%20pods%20everywhere](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-schedule-pods-on-kubernetes-control-plane-node/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20be,taint%20on%20the%20master%20nodes.&text=This%20will%20remove%20the%20node,able%20to%20schedule%20pods%20everywhere)

( unless you have configured it to accept pods deployment? Btw, correct me if i am wrong but your kubectl get pod -o wide shows us 3ips but you have only two nodes right? )

Keep in touch.

Comment: Thanks for  your reply, i  have small doubt if i remove the taint label in master node then pods going to scheduled the  nodes like master and worker, suppose if one pod is being created and then  if the pod is scheduled to run in  worker node then master node not able to get the application work load right

Comment: Then dont use nodeport but use LoadBalancer service type or use an ingress controller like nginx ingress for example ??